# how to use prestashop login system with other webpages(outside from shop) in my site?

Tags: php, cookies, prestashop-1.6

Dear friends I have installed prestashop on my existing website.My current website has a login system that I have already built.

Because of installing prestashop for my system,I thought to change my existing login to prestashop login.

As for the prestashop documentation,to access prestashop cookie outside prestashop,I made a test page to retrieve cookie data as follows,

```
include_once('path_to_prestashop/config/config.inc.php');
include_once('path_to_prestashop/config/settings.inc.php');
include_once('path_to_prestashop/classes/Cookie.php');
$cookie = new Cookie('ps');
print_r($cookie);
```

But this is not working and browser says

**It contains redirect loop.**

I tried to disable `SEO friendly url` and `cannonical url to no-direct` as some posts suggested.

Now if I go to the test page it redirects to the prestashop index page rather displaying cookie data.

What should I do to overcome this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: No-one has any answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include `config/config.inc.php` PrestaShop redirects to the shop domain.

The following code is causing this behavior in `classes/shop/Shop.php`:

```
$shop = new Shop($id_shop);
if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($shop) || !$shop->active)
{
  // No shop found ... too bad, let's redirect to default shop
  $default_shop = new Shop(Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DEFAULT'));

  // Hmm there is something really bad in your Prestashop !
  if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($default_shop))
    throw new PrestaShopException('Shop not found');

  $params = $_GET;
  unset($params['id_shop']);
  $url = $default_shop->domain;
  if (!Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS'))
    $url .= $default_shop->getBaseURI().'index.php?'.http_build_query($params);
  else
  {
    // Catch url with subdomain "www"
    if (strpos($url, 'www.') === 0 && 'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === $url || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'www.'.$url)
      $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    else
      $url .= $default_shop->getBaseURI();

    if (count($params))
      $url .= '?'.http_build_query($params);
  }
  $redirect_type = Configuration::get('PS_CANONICAL_REDIRECT') == 2 ? '301' : '302';
  header('HTTP/1.0 '.$redirect_type.' Moved');
  header('location: http://'.$url);
  exit;
}
```

You could override the `Shop` class to disable the redirect for your script.

To do this first define `PS_DISABLE_SHOP_REDIRECT` constant before you include `config/config.inc.php`:

```
define('PS_DISABLE_SHOP_REDIRECT', true);
```

Then paste the following before the previous code in the overridden class:

```
if (defined('PS_DISABLE_SHOP_REDIRECT')) {
  $id_shop = Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DEFAULT');
}
```